# How to know there is no .so when dlopen()

Tags: c++, plugins, dlopen

I made plugin for my project using dlopen.

I want to make my main program stop trying to load plugin again when there is no so.

Is there any good solution for this? 
Do I need to compare dlerror message?

Please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [manpage](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlopen.3.html):

> If `dlopen()` fails for any reason, it returns `NULL`.

There is also a really extensive example.

> ### EXAMPLE
>
> The program below loads the (glibc) math library, looks up the
>   address of the [cos(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/cos.3.html) function, and prints the cosine of 2.0.  The
>   following is an example of building and running the program:
>
> ```
> $ cc dlopen_demo.c -ldl
> $ ./a.out
> -0.416147
> ```
>
> #### Program source
>
> ```
> #include <stdio.h>
> #include <stdlib.h>
> #include <dlfcn.h>
> #include <gnu/lib-names.h>  /* Defines LIBM_SO (which will be a
>                                string such as "libm.so.6") */
> int
> main(void)
> {
>     void *handle;
>     double (*cosine)(double);
>     char *error;
>
>     handle = dlopen(LIBM_SO, RTLD_LAZY);
>     if (!handle) {
>         fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", dlerror());
>         exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
>     }
>
>     dlerror();    /* Clear any existing error */
>
>     cosine = (double (*)(double)) dlsym(handle, "cos");
>
>     /* According to the ISO C standard, casting between function
>        pointers and 'void *', as done above, produces undefined results.
>        POSIX.1-2003 and POSIX.1-2008 accepted this state of affairs and
>        proposed the following workaround:
>
>            *(void **) (&cosine) = dlsym(handle, "cos");
>
>        This (clumsy) cast conforms with the ISO C standard and will
>        avoid any compiler warnings.
>
>        The 2013 Technical Corrigendum to POSIX.1-2008 (a.k.a.
>        POSIX.1-2013) improved matters by requiring that conforming
>        implementations support casting 'void *' to a function pointer.
>        Nevertheless, some compilers (e.g., gcc with the '-pedantic'
>        option) may complain about the cast used in this program. */
>
>     error = dlerror();
>     if (error != NULL) {
>         fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", error);
>         exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
>     }
>
>     printf("%f\n", (*cosine)(2.0));
>     dlclose(handle);
>     exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
> }
> ```